# vba in word/excel returning wrong character set

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am struggling to get my code to display æ ø å.

```
contentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"

Set O = New HTMLDocument
Set objRequest = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")       'CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP") '

With objRequest
   .Open "POST", my_url, False
   '.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", contentType
   .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=iso-8859-1"
   .send
End With

O.body.innerHTML = objRequest.responseText
Debug.Print O.body.innerHTML
```

Here is the output
348 , Kim Sk?n , KS , 0 ,
Which should have been Skåtun

If I open it in IE(There its displayed correct) and look at the source I get this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<title>Logg skjema Ansatt liste</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">

<html>
<body>
348 , Kim Skåtun , KS , 0 , <br>


</body>
</html>
```

I tried utf-8 as well with the same result, any ideas how to work around this in word with vba?

Comment: a) Why the POST with `x-www-form-urlencoded` when you are not sending a POST string? b) These type of questions are virtually impossible to answer without the URL If you cannot provide the URL then provide a public one that duplicates the problem.

Comment: `Debug.Print O.body.innerHTML` will give you those `?` in Immediate window. Where are you writing to Word?

Comment: @Siddarth Rout - I am not writing to word, i assign it to a variable which I then use in a combobox in a form.

Comment: @ Jeeped - I will try to find a place where I can publish the information from the SQL database. The url I am using is only on the network, sorry for the inconvinience